# Recommendation for small, low-cost, low-energy, fanless, 80686 or x86-64 computer with at least 3 SATA ports using normal connectors instead of mSATA

Tags: motherboard, sata, embedded-systems, mini-pc, fanless

Per the post subject, is there an x86 computer like this that I can still buy or otherwise acquire in 2019?  Used or refurbished is OK as long as it is still reliable.  I want a low-cost, low-energy, fanless, small, 80686 (including CMOV instructions, so VIA C7 is OK but VIA C3 is not) or x86-64 computer with at least three SATA ports using normal connectors, as used by 2.5-inch HDDs and SSDs, instead of mSATA to replace some full-size ATX tower computers with fans and using Core 2 and earlier hardware platforms.  Ideally, I want to continue using the current installations of Ubuntu 10.04.x LTS for x86-32 from 2011 because it still works for my application so I want to avoid the chore of upgrading the OS only to use a newer computer.  The primary market lifetime (correct term?) of x86 motherboards is frustratingly short for someone like me who still does not have a newer than Core 2 era x86 computer in 2019 because the Core 2 era and earlier x86 computers I use still suffice for my application.  I use the same computer hardware until the hardware, such as through-hole electrolytic capacitors, fails.  I have found some small, such as Mini-ITX, motherboards with at least three SATA ports using normal connectors but they seem to no longer be for sale by the time I find them, years after they were released.  For example, here is a fanless AMD x86-64 Mini-ITX motherboard with six SATA ports using normal connectors:

https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/C60M1I/

Unfortunately, I cannot find anywhere that still sells this model.  The hardware does not need to be current;  the computers I want to replace use hardware platforms aged at least a decade.  I really want to avoid the chore of upgrading the OS only to use a newer computer but I can try to upgrade the OS if necessary or maybe only retrofit a build of a newer than 2.6.32.x Linux kernel into the current installation of Ubuntu 10.04.x LTS from 2011.  I think even a Pentium II computer will suffice for my application if it meets the SATA requirements.  I need one Ethernet port, preferably (at least) Gigabit Ethernet;  Fast Ethernet is the minimum.  I prefer Intel over Realtek for Ethernet controllers but Realtek should suffice as long as it is reliable.  I live in Canada.  On NewEgg.ca , I can filter Mini-ITX motherboards to only those with at least three SATA ports, which eliminates all but two models.  One of these models was eliminated because it costs over 1 000 CAD and I do not remember why the other model was eliminated.  On Amazon.ca , I can narrow down motherboards to Mini-ITX but cannot filter the results by cooling type (fanless) nor by number of SATA ports.  It seems that most models of Mini-ITX and smaller x86 motherboards only have up to two SATA ports using normal connectors.  Some motherboards may have at least three SATA ports including mSATA sockets but the drives I am currently using are 2.5-inch or larger and I want to continue using them instead of having to buy mSATA drives.  I bought 2.5-inch SATA SSDs instead of mSATA SSDs because I bought the drives for use with microATX or larger motherboards that use normal SATA connectors instead of mSATA;  I thought it was better to reduce the number of connectors required to connect the drive to the motherboard to reduce long-term reliability problems caused by connectors than to have more modularity/interchangeability by using mSATA drives.  As for the definition of “small”, I want microATX at the largest.  As for “low cost”, I am used to paying <=15 CAD for an Intel Core 2 Duo E8400 CPU and around 50 CAD for a used or refurbished Socket T AKA LGA775 motherboard when I buy five of the same model of motherboard at once.  Yes, I realise that these computers have fans but I am trying to give an idea of what I mean by “low cost”.  Anyway, Amazon has too many models of Mini-ITX motherboards to go through them one by one to see if any are fanless and have at least three SATA ports using normal connectors.  I did find this Core 2 era Mini-ITX motherboard with four SATA ports using normal connectors but I do not know if it is feasible to use this motherboard without any fan?

https://www.amazon.ca/Jetway-NF93R-LF-Mini-ITX-Motherboard-Processors/dp/B003Y3TWFO/ref=sr_1_20?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1560625682&refinements=p_n_feature_six_browse-bin%3A7328511011&rnid=7328506011&s=electronics&sr=1-20

Edit #1: I prefer to buy x86-64 hardware in case I later need to use an x86-64 OS but, because I am currently using an x86-32 OS, I can still use an 80686 computer with CMOV instructions.

I searched this database of single-board computers for x86 computers with SATA connectivity:

https://www.hackerboards.com/search.php?type=&q=&price_min=&price_max=&cpu_speed_min=&cpu_cores=&cpu_arch=x86&ram_min=&storage_min=&sata=on&lan_speed=0&usb_min=&gpio_min=&dim_max_1=&dim_max_2=&weight=&order=price&order_d=a

but the only computers with at least three SATA ports looks like they will cost far too much and, regardless, they are overkill for my application.

Comment: When you write questions, don't hesitate to add paragraphs. Huge walls of text are difficult to read, and some may prefer skipping your question, lowering your chances to receive an answer.

Comment: Unreadable, sorry. Please break the text up.  It is good that you are provided a lot of details, but they are not well presented. The more presentable the question to better the response.

Comment: What are you using this computer for? If applicable, what should the maximum total dimensions, case included, be? What's your budget? Would you be willing to buy used?

Comment: It is multiple computers, not only one.  Among other uses, the computers automatically back up the file system of other computers over the network.  One of the computers uses custom software I developed for the backup system, which is part of the reason I do not want to upgrade the OS.

Comment: Maximum dimensions: approximately 30 cm high × 30 cm deep × 18 cm wide or smaller would be nice but I do not really have a hard requirement as long as it fits in the space I currently have.

As the second sentence of my post says, used or refurbished is OK as long as it is still reliable.

Budget: I do not have a hard limit except I do not want to spend a lot of money on it because the decade+ old computers I currently use still work but produce waste heat and fan noise.  I do not want to spend lots of money on hardware much more powerful than I need nor that requires upgrading the OS.

Comment: Correction: at least three of the computers use custom software I developed for the backup system.

Comment: Hi Brolin, this is a question and answer site, not a forum.  Please extract your answer and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up buying five fanless AMD APU-based Mini-ITX x86-64 motherboards on eBay: three of the Asus C60M1-I because that was all the seller had then one Asus E35M1-I and one Asus E35M1-I DeLuxe. These models of motherboards are from around 2011, still support legacy boot even though they use EFI instead of BIOS, and the r8169 driver for Realtek Gigabit Ethernet controllers in the Debian/Ubuntu releases from around 2011 to 2013 seems to work well with the Gigabit Ethernet controllers integrated on the motherboards. I am still using the same OS installations on the same physical SATA SSDs but, with a single order from Mini-Box.com, I used the picoPSU to eliminate the fans in the power supplies and used the M350 enclosure to shrink the chasses from full-size ATX to Mini-ITX, only 2.5 litres per computer except for the external AC adapter for the picoPSU and one of the computers has the third SATA SSD sticking out with the top of the chassis not installed because this model of chassis is only designed for one or two 2.5-inch drives so the third drive does not fit normally in the chassis.  I placed the order on 2023‑08‑15 for six of the ENC‑M350‑PWR (M350 Enclosure with PicoPSU-80W and 60W adapter kit) at 79 USD each = 474 USD; six of the M350 HDD bracket for mounting a second 2.5-inch drive in the M350 enclosure at 2.79 USD each = 16.74 USD; and six of the “P4-POWER-MINI-Barracuda” “P4” Mini Power Cable for PicoPSU-80 at 1.35 USD each = 8.10 USD and with quotation marks because calling this cable a P4 as in Pentium 4 cable is both an anachronism and a misnomer because it is simply the 4-pin 12-volt CPU power cable for ATX12V motherboards covering many more generations and varieties of hardware than Pentium 4.  Anyway, the subtotal is 498.84 USD plus 78.47 USD for DHL to deliver the single large parcel from Mini-Box.com in Fremont, California to me in Delta, British Columbia = total price 577.31 USD converted to CAD because I have a Canadian credit card account.  This solution still works well since I assembled the Mini-ITX computers in the summer.  I chose the 80-watt picoPSU board because apparently only the 80-watt model has the connector for the 4-pin 12-volt CPU power cable that is needed for the Mini-ITX motherboards I am using.  The M350 enclosure/chassis has a black plastic cover for the front to hide a SSD or other USB device connected to the front USB connectors and presumably to dampen the light from the supernova blue LEDs on the front of the enclosure but I did not install these covers because they seem unnecessary.  Even though all five of the Mini-ITX computers are on the desktop as in furniture in my bedroom, I can still sleep with the room lit by all of the supernova blue LEDs on the front of the enclosures but some persons may dislike all of this light at night.  This model of enclosure does not have a reset switch nor a drive activity indicator light but I guess someone who is into hardware hacking more than me and wants these hardware features could add their own switch and LED to connect to the headers on the motherboard.  I will try to add before and after photographs after posting this answer.  Edit: I lost motivation to follow through on adding before and after photographs even though I already have photographs from months ago that I could use.

Answer (score 0):

Low-cost, low-energy and fanless? **Raspberry Pi**. In order to connect your three hard disks, you may want to purchase an **external HDD case**. You can either have two of them, one for two disks, another one for the remaining one, or find a case which can be used with three or four disks (there is much less choice for them compared to one or two disks cases, but you can still find ones).

With a Raspberry Pi, you get an Ethernet port and Wi-Fi connectivity, four USB connectors (two to three left after you connect the hard disks) for your devices, an HDMI port to connect a monitor, and an audio jack. Don't forget an SD card for the operating system.

It is not particularly fun to use as a desktop computer, but it doesn't seem that you're looking for the latest hardware for a gaming platform anyway, so...

In terms of the cost, Raspberry Pi with its official case costs about 45 USD. Add 10 USD for the SD card. The most expensive part would be the HDD cases, at least 75 USD, probably more. If you don't have an USB charger to power the Raspberry Pi, add extra 15 USD (don't buy a cheap one, as it won't be able to provide enough power for the device and the three disks).

Comment: I need an x86 computer with at least three SATA ports, not an ARM computer with zero SATA ports.  [DFI](https://www.dfi.com/) has some Mini-ITX motherboards with four SATA ports using normal connectors and some other small x86 computers with at least three SATA ports using normal connectors but does not have pricing on their Web site and I do not know if all of these small x86 computers that meet my SATA requirements may be used without a fan because at least some of these motherboards do not include a CPU.

Comment: With OP on this one. Even ignoring the explicit requirement for x86, as much as I love the Pi, it probably doesn't make sense here; perhaps the Pi 4 thanks to the full Gigabit ethernet and USB 3, but still, probably not the best.

Comment: @JMY1000: why not? The problem is that the OP said absolutely nothing about the reason he wants x86 or SATA ports on motherboard (and there is nothing which would indicate there *is* a reason in the first place). And I won't ask him for the details either, since when I recommended him to add paragraphs, he answered that I have attention-deficit disorder (comment removed later), so I'm not willing to help the OP any longer.

Comment: Fair points; we are lacking a lot of info, thus my comment asking for more. However, x86 is a common requirement for many programs, and SATA provides significant benefits over USB; given there are other, likely nearly-as-cheap alternatives to a Pi that don't compromise here, at the cost of power consumption and size, it seems unlikely the Pi is the best answer. I'm still waiting on more info from the OP so I can write my answer. Sidenote: those comments were flagged, which is why I presume they were removed.

Comment: I have not removed any comment;  someone else did.  I appreciate you trying to help me and did not intend to offend you but I seriously do not think my original post is very long.  Anyway, as I said, I want to continue using the same OS installations on the same physical drives as I am currently using, which is why I need an x86 computer with SATA Host ports.  Even if I wanted to switch to an ARM computer, why not choose one with SATA connectivity?  I gather that the Raspberry Pi version 4 is out now but I have not yet researched it but I am assuming that it still lacks SATA connectivity?

Comment: I redd about the newly-released Raspberry Pi 4 Model B;  apparently I was correct that it still lacks ATA (Parallel or Serial) connectivity.

Comment: I replaced the Socket A tower computer in my bedroom with an Asus UL30VT model of Core 2 ULV notebook computer that still has a fan but I do not know if the fan is running because even if it is I cannot hear it over the fan noise from the Core 2 tower computer (desktop Core 2, LGA775/Socket T motherboard) beside the UL30VT.  I know I said I wanted a fanless computer but I was given the UL30VT, which works well even still with the Ubuntu 10.04.x LTS OS from 2011.  I already had lots of old notebook computers but I could not use them because they use a 2.5-inch PATA HDD instead of 2.5-inch SATA.

Comment: Long story short, I got two HP Small Form Factor (SFF) Core 2 Duo desktop computers free of charge from my local hackspace and I wanted to use the UL30VT as a portable computer with another drive I had so I moved the SSD from the UL30VT that was originally in my Socket A tower computer to one of the Core 2 SFF desktop computers, which seem quite quiet even though they have at least two fans.  I also still do not have to upgrade from Ubuntu 10.04.x LTS from 2011 so I am happy for now but I do not have a spare power supply that will fit in this SFF computer so I hope I can still buy one.

Comment: These computers are still in use, almost always running, without any known hardware failure but the only things spinning are fans because I have replaced all of the HDDs in the computers we still use with SSDs in 2020.  I bought three of the Asus C60M1-I motherboard on eBay but have not yet tried this model of motherboard.  I found one Jetway NF93R-LF motherboard for sale on eBay but have not bought it because it has a fan connector but I only want it if it may be used without a fan.  I asked the seller if the motherboard requires a fan but have not heard back from them after around one week.

Comment: warning to those hoping to use rpi with 2.5 hdds! rpi outputs 1.2a combined on all usb ports. i was unable to power two 2.5 hdds, each rated for 5v 1a. drives flicker and spin up and down, which is not exactly ideal for them. it's possible the official power supply might help, but still the limitation on the ports would remain. there is a mod to run a wire to usb bus to circumvent this, but it requires soldering and is not trivial. another option is a usb hub with external power. given all this i advise against considering rpi for driving multiple usb-powered hdds.